# Get increment number from form with php

Tags: php, forms, increment

I have this code. I think here: name="season[]" must be a number. I don't know how to get that number, or can someone help me to get this code work.

Code:

```
function addmorespisode(){
   $("#allepisode").html("");
   for(var i=1;i<=parseInt($("#expisodenumber").val());i++) {
      $("#allepisode").append('<tr><td><label for="fname">episodes for season '+i+'<span></span>: </label></td><td><input value="Season '+i+'" name="season[]"  type="hidden" /><input value=""  type="number" name="episode[]"  /><br/><input type="checkbox" name="includeepisode[]" value="1"  unchecked="">include episode 0</td></tr>');
   }
}
```

Comment: `season[]` work like an array of input. you can go with that.

Comment: Can you show me an example please? Thanks

Comment: on the action page of your form try to get these value by `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this? I need to count number of seasons